# laravel 5.6 insert an href into message redirect

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem to insert a redirect link into a message in a redirect laravel command. 
This is what I woould to have:

```
return redirect('validation')->with('warning','to correct mistake, click here');
```

and after click on the here, I have to load another page with the url mapped on here. 
Something like this, but this solution not work:

```
return redirect('validation')->with('warning','to correct mistake, click <a href="#top">here</a>');
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What did you expect? And what actually happened?

Comment: the href: return redirect('validation')->with('warning','to correct mistake, click <a href="#top">here</a>'); not works... I see a warning message with no interpretation tags, i see on the message excatly this:to correct mistake, click <a href="#top">here</a>

Comment: Can we see your view ?

Comment: i think this was an alert right?

Answer (score 3):

I think you using the this in you view to show the warning.

```
{{ session('warning') }}
```

You need to use these brackets in your view to show the warning and to allow the html to be processed by the browser.

```
{!! session('warning') !!}
```

These brackets `{{ }}` escape html tags and will render html as plain text to prevent XSS attacks.

If you want to inject html from the backend you must use `{!! $html !!}` which will render the html as html.

You can checkout the [Displaying Date -- Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#displaying-data) for a better explanation.

Comment: yep. <div class="alert alert-warning alert-block">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
 <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
</div> How can I avoid this situation  keeping the structure unaltered